# iPhone - Remove view and NavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I have a ViewController which creates a NavigationController and puts a UIView in it.

```
nvcontrol =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuView];
...
UIView *parent = self.view.superview;
[parent addSubview:nvcontrol.view];
```

I need to close the view (incl. the NavController) from within the child-viewcontroller.

The following snippet I tried, only closes the view inside the NavController, not the NavController itself. This ends up showing the blue head with a white space below.

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

What could solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried this but I think something like this should work:

```
[self.navigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Almost, but not yet. It takes away the child view and the Navbar at the top, but then the screen is white

Comment: My guess is that it probably has something to do with the view underneath needing to be redrawn or refreshed. But, rather than go down that route, I think there may be a simple approach. It sounds like your nav controller and its children become the primary view controllers when you show them. Why don't you use presentModalViewController:animated to show them? Then you can do dismissModalViewController to get rid of them. Google those method names and you'll find plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

@traingle_man Are you sure view is a property of uinavigation controller?

If I understand your question correct, this may help

```
[nvcontrol.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Take note `nvcontrol` is not visible (in the scope) inside the child-viewcontroller.

Comment: Yes, UINavigationController inherits the view property from UIViewController.